# Creating a Host group for multiple servers in Control-M

Tags: control-m

I am trying to create a host group in Control-M, so that my jobs can be run on more than one servers. How do I do this using BMC Control-M. I am using Version V8.00.

Answer (score 1):

From the Tools menu, select Hosts Management > Hosts Manager.
Click add ("plus" icon)

All this (and many more) is explained in depth in BMC Control-M documentation.